# Cant get to second read [Prolog]

Tags: input, prolog, output

Im having trouble with these reads, I can read the first value, then it doesn't print the second write and goes back to the menu:

```
adicionar_viagens :-
write('Nova Partida:'),nl,
read(nova_partida),nl,
write('Novo Destino:'),nl,
read(novo_destino),nl,
write('Hora Partida:'),nl,
read(nova_hora_partida),nl,
write('Novo Chegada:'),nl,
read(novo_hora_chegada),nl,
write('Preco:'),nl,
read(novo_preco),nl.
```

Answer (score 0):

In Prolog, variables start with either an underscore or a upper case letter. But in the argument to the `read/1` calls you're using atoms (i.e. constants). Thus, the the calls will only succeed if the term read unifies with those atoms. The calls will fail if you input something else, making the call to the `adicionar_viagens/0` predicate fail and the behavior you're observing. Change your code to:

```
adicionar_viagens :-
    write('Nova Partida:'), nl,
    read(Nova_partida), nl,
    write('Novo Destino:'), nl,
    read(Novo_destino), nl,
    write('Hora Partida:'), nl,
    read(Nova_hora_partida), nl,
    write('Novo Chegada:'), nl,
    read(Novo_hora_chegada), nl,
    write('Preco:'), nl,
    read(Novo_preco), nl.
```

But why read values if you're not doing anything with those values in this clause? If you want to pass the values to the caller of this predicate, then you will need to add the variables to the clause head:

```
adicionar_viagens(Nova_partida, Novo_destino, Nova_hora_partida, Novo_hora_chegada, Novo_preco) :-
    ...
```

You can also simplify the variable names given that all of them refer to a new trip. For example:

```
adicionar_viagens(Partida, Destino, Hora_partida, Hora_chegada, Preco) :-
    ...
```